# How to write this array as a php loop

Tags: php

I have the follow array, how do I write a loop to list the name and id?

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test name
                [id] => 110
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test name 2
                [id] => 111
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test name 3
                [id] => 124
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test name 4
                [id] => 105
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [name] => Test name 5
                [id] => 56
            )

    )
```

)

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
foreach ($array['data'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['name'];
    echo $value['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy one:

```
foreach($array['data'] as $item){
    echo $item['id'].'. '.$item['name'];
}
```